# Struts2 with Nested Iterator dynamic column and rows

Tags: struts2, iterator

I want to display grid in Struts2 which include dynamic rows and columns, it also provide that data should be save in database.
so i have created one list for columns and other map for that values in one bean.

I have included code also.

My bean looks like

```
public class Annexure{
    private List<String> columnsList = new ArrayList<String>(1);
   private Map<String,List<String>> columnsValues = new HashMap<String,List<String>>(1);
   ... setter/getter methods
}
```

### Action class

```
package com.eks.ias.web.annexure.action;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.eks.ias.web.annexure.vo.Annexure;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
public class AnnexureAction extends ActionSupport {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8819437646232339486L;

private Annexure annexure = new Annexure();

public String execute()throws Exception {

    List<String> columnsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    columnsList.add("STNNo");
    columnsList.add("EAN");
    columnsList.add("ArticleCode");
    annexure.setColumnsList(columnsList);

    annexure.setTotalColumns(3);
    annexure.setName("Stock Pending for Inward in SAP");
    annexure.setDescription("Details of all merchandise physically received");
    annexure.setSiteName("XXX");

    Map<String,List<String>> columnsValues = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
    columnsValues.put("0", columnsList);
    columnsValues.put("1", columnsList);
    annexure.setColumnsValues(columnsValues);
    return SUCCESS;
    }

public void setAnnexure(Annexure annexure) {
    this.annexure = annexure;
}
public Annexure getAnnexure() {
    return annexure;
}
    }
```

### JSP page

```
<s:iterator value="annexure.columnsValues" status="rows">
    <tr>
    <s:iterator value="annexure.columnsList" status="columns">
    <td><s:textfield name="annexure.columnsValues[%{#rows.index}][%{#columns.index}]" theme="simple"/></td>
    </s:iterator>
    </tr>
 </s:iterator>
```

Html code generated looks like

```
<tr>
     <td>
    <input type="text" name="annexure.columnsValues[0][0]" value="STNNo" 
         id="annexure_annexure_columnsValues_0__0_"/>
       </td>
       <td>
      <input type="text" name="annexure.columnsValues[0][1]" value="EAN" 
          id="annexure_annexure_columnsValues_0__1_"/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <input type="text" name="annexure.columnsValues[0][2]" value="ArticleCode"  
            id="annexure_annexure_columnsValues_0__2_"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

when i submit data then  i am not able to get those data in action
I am not able to understand the problem if data populate then data should get in action also.

Comment: you want the data in same action an din same format?

Comment: yes, save and edit kind of screen

Comment: can you show your action class?

Comment: List<String> columnsList = new ArrayList<String>();
columnsList.add("STNNo");
columnsList.add("EAN");
columnsList.add("ArticleCode");
annexure.setColumnsList(columnsList);
annexure.setTotalColumns(3);
annexure.setName("Stock Pending for Inward in SAP");
annexure.setDescription("Details of all merchandise physically");
annexure.setSiteName("XXX");
     
Map<String,List<String>> columnsValues = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();  columnsValues.put("0", columnsList);     columnsValues.put("1", columnsList);   annexure.setColumnsValues(columnsValues);

Comment: i am assuming that you have both `getter` and `setters` for `columnsList` and `columnsValues` in action class?

Comment: no its available in Annexure and setter/getter for Annexure is available in Action

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have enough rep to post a comment, and I'm not sure whether I understand your problem fully. However, there is one thing that I noted with the row index.

shouldn't this

```
<s:textfield name="annexure.columnsValues[%{#rows.index}][%{#columns.index}]" theme="simple"/>
```

rather be

```
<s:textfield name="annexure.columnsValues['%{#rows.index}'][%{#columns.index}]" theme="simple"/>
```

Note the single quotes. This should set the string key correctly in the map.

Comment: its giving error like 2012-01-06 10:48:06,335 WARN  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error setting expression 'annexure.columnsValues['0']['0']' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@13e7f59': ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty(null, "0", [Ljava.lang.String;@13e7f59)
 at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2239) [:]
 at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127) [:]
 at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220) [:]

Comment: @user1057928, Can you provide the full action class code? You can edit the question and update it.

Comment: i paste the full action class in my question

Answer (score 0):

Code will be something like this

```
<s:iterator value="lstBean" id="lstBean" status="outerStat">
        <s:textfield value="%{name}" name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].name"/>
        <s:textfield value="%{amt}" name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].amt"/>
        <s:textfield value="%{id}" name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].id"/>
        <s:iterator value="%{lstString}" status="myStat">
            <s:textfield name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].lstString[%{#myStat.index}]"/>
        </s:iterator>
    </s:iterator>
```

Here's the complete example on [Nested Iterator in Struts2](http://www.onlinexamples.com/showfullexample.action?idexamples=10&title=Nested%20Iterators%20Example)

Comment: Its always better to provide some explanation rather than giving a link only