# Dynamic struts2 object field name

Tags: struts2, iterator

I'm trying to generate a table with its columns dynamically.

Currently, this is my code:

```
<s:iterator value='entities' var="entity">
  <tr>
    <s:iterator value="beanMD.fieldsMetaData" var="fieldMD" >
      <td><s:property value="#entity.email"/> <!-- Prints OK :  email@email.com --> 
      <s:property value="#fieldMD.value.name"/> <!-- Prints OK :  email-->

       <s:property value="#entity.%{#fieldMD.value.name}" /> <!--  Nothing -->
       <s:property value="#entity.%{fieldMD.value.name}" /> <!--  Nothing -->
       <s:property value="entity.%{fieldMD.value.name}" /> <!--  Nothing -->
       <s:property value="entity.%{#fieldMD.value.name}" /> <!--  Nothing -->

     </td>
   </s:iterator>
  </tr>
</iterator>
```

- entities it's the collection with the beans with the data.
- `beanMD.fieldsMetadata` is a Map, which contains the attributes of the entities.

In the example above, I used the attribute "email" as an example. If I ask directly the attribute, it returns OK. If I ask the column name, it also is OK.
But I can´t find a way to use the together.

This post seems related, 
[Struts2 with Nested Iterator dynamic column and rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740062/struts2-with-nested-iterator-dynamic-column-and-rows)
but it uses all Maps, and didn't help me much.

Comment: It's a different scripting variables how do you want to use it together may very. Clarify what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square brackets to get value from the bean.

```
<s:property value="#entity[#fieldMD.value.name]" />
```

It is possible because internally OGNL treats following expressions exactly the same.

So

```
<s:property value="date.time" />
```

and

```
<s:property value="date['time']" />
```

produces the same result.

Comment: Thank you so much @aleksandr-m, you saved my day. 
    <s:property value="#entity[#fieldMD.value.name]" />
worked perfectly.

Comment: Hi @aleksandr-m, I have trouble again. What I'm triyng to achieve now is to get a property from the previous expresion. Like:
    `<s:property value="#entity[#fieldMD.value.name].id" />`
or using your example
    `<s:property value="#entity[#fieldMD.value.name][id]" />`

I'm not able to get anything from this, and my real case is also more complicated, i want to get something like:
    `<s:property value="#entity[#fieldMD.value.name][#fieldMD.value.showPropery]" />`
Is this even posible?
Regards

Comment: I solved this using `<s:set>`
`<s:set var="mappedEntity" value="#entity[#fieldMD.value.name]" />
<td><s:property value="#mappedEntity[#fieldMD.value.descriptionField]"/></td>`