# Using Struts2 Iterate an ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, action

I am trying to display the result of the select query.

PS - I don't want to print the value by typing in the Each Parameter name.
As there are lot of columns.

So what can be the best option and how can I achieve it?

My thought process was to Iterate an ArrayList of ArrayList but how can I do that without the name of each parameter.

In Action Class:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> al ;
// It stores the data in this fashion
  al  0->{"abcd","bccd","bank","ased"}
      1->{"visa","Bhan","okas","adwq"}
      ........
      ........

// In Display .jsp

  <s:iterator value="al">
      <S:iterator ...//that's where I am stuck..
</s>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm really not sure how you're trying to accomplish this.  Do you have any code that you may want to include for this purpose?

Comment: Actually this is the first time I am trying struts2.
I will edit the my question to include bit of code.

Comment: What with this pseudo-code you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116233/dynamic-struts2-object-field-name helps?